# How do I add an offset to a Poisson regression using sklearn.linear_model.PoissonRegressor

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I am doing a Poisson regression of sample_df["vaccination_count"] over sample_df["Uninsured"] here and need to understand how would I use the sample_df["population"] column as an offset to the regression. Where could I add the sample_df['population'] as an offset to the PoissonRegressor()

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # To visualize
import pandas as pd  
from sklearn.linear_model import PoissonRegressor
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sample_df=pd.read_csv('test.csv')

sample_df['vaccination_count'].fillna(sample_df['vaccination_count'].mean(), inplace=True) 

Y=(sample_df['vaccination_count'].values.reshape(-1,1))

X=sample_df['Uninsured'].values.reshape(-1,1)

X.reshape(46,1)

Y.reshape(46,1)

regr=PoissonRegressor() 


regr.fit(X, Y)

plt.figure()

fig = plt.gcf()

fig.set_size_inches(5,5)

plt.plot(X, regr.predict(X), color='blue', linewidth=1)
```

[The output I see seems correct for the code, but I need to still add population as an offset to the poisson regression, as per my question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrWwo.jpg)

[Also, the csv is included here for reference as well](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PS-VoD1khxC5y1uaTuRiYhKd5n-d60XN/view?usp=sharing)